# Negative lookahead to exclude whole line based on char set possible?

Tags: notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have a large text file in Notepad++ where I'd like to find certain lines. Let's say it looks something like:

```
I don't like numbers 1 2 and 3

I don't like most symbols either, ! @ and # are bad

But I do like lines with no numbers and only symbols . and *
```

In the above I'd like to exclude those lines in the file that have numbers and all symbols except a period or (say) an asterisk.

I now know that negative lookahead/behind don't work this way but what I mean to do is something like mate a negative lookahead conditional like (?!=[\d]) or [^\d] together with a search for lines with words like ^[A-Za-z.*\s]+$ but where the entire line gets rejected on the negative match regardless of where in the line it occurs.

Comment: Why won't positive matching work?  

`cat myfile.txt | grep -E '^[A-Za-z*\.\s]+$' > newfile.txt`

Comment: Thanks but this is in Notepad++.... don't really know Linux!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want to remove all lines that do not conform to the `^[A-Za-z.*\s]+$` pattern. In this case, just use

**Find What**: `(^[A-Za-z.*\s]+$\R*)|.*\R*`
**Replace With**: `$1`

**Details**:

- `(^[A-Za-z.*\s]+$\R?)` - Capturing group #1 (referred to with `$1` backreference) matching:

  - `^` - start of line
  - `[A-Za-z.*\s]+` - 1 or more chars that are ASCII letters, `.`, `*` or whitespace (`\s`) (replace with `\h` to only match horizontal wjitespaces)
  - `$` - end of line
  - `\R*` - 0 or more line breaks
- `|` - or
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars
- `\R*` - 0 or more line breaks.

The `$1` inserts good lines back.

[image]